# Fourier transform of \$x(t) =t^2e^{-|t|}\$

Tags: signal, signal-processing, math, fourier

I have to find the Fourier transform of this function.

[image]

(- sign exists BEFORE modulus). I thought of using this standard result.

[image]

If I split this fourier transform into this will it be correct to use this standard result. [image]

Otherwise do I have to intergrate this by hand - I thought of using the convolution theoram but firstly I cannot work out the Fourier transform of t^2 (when I try using the fourier transfer equation I get 0) and I also cannot find 
that in any standard signal processing books.

I have also sketched this function in the time domain.
[image] 
Please can you advise me on this question.

Comment: Have you checked [with WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Fourier+transform+calculator&rawformassumption=%7B%22F%22,+%22FourierTransformCalculator%22,+%22transformfunction%22%7D+-%3E%22t%5E2e%5E-%7Ct%7C%22&rawformassumption=%7B%22F%22,+%22FourierTransformCalculator%22,+%22variable1%22%7D+-%3E%22t%22&rawformassumption=%7B%22F%22,+%22FourierTransformCalculator%22,+%22variable2%22%7D+-%3E%22x%22&rawformassumption=%7B%22MC%22,%22%22%7D-%3E%7B%22Formula%22%7D)? Oh, and the function in your title doesn't match the function in your question.

Comment: I am very sorry, it was just a typing accident. I will the title change it immediately.

Comment: I changed the title

Comment: I know it's related but wouldn't he get a quicker answer on http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your representation of the negative branch of the function is incorrect.Try putting  $$t=-\infty $$ to see that your function diverges as opposed to the definition.The correct integral is as stated:
$$X(\omega)=\int_{0}^\infty t^2 exp(-j\omega t-t) dt +\int_{-\infty}^0 t^2 exp(-j\omega t+t)dt$$ (In most mathematical problems you might find $$\frac{1}{(\sqrt{2\pi})}$$ multiplied to the integral,so do adjust that for yourself.)

I think you are talking about trying to evaluate it from your available results.
In that case try writing 
$$f(t)=t^2e^{-t}u(t)+t^2e^tu(-t)$$
You can use the results you have stated along with the time scaling property for the required integral.

I think this is a homework problem,so I leave the final values for you to figure out.

Comment: Thank you sir you have really helped me. I very much understand  your explanation

Comment: Can you please tell me if you mean use the time scaling property for U(t) in the standard result (t^2)*(e^t)*U(-t). Also how to do that?

Comment: do you mean to use u(-t)=1-u(t)

Comment: @Saavin, Isn't the second term in the addition a time reversed signal? What is the fourier transform of $$f(-t)$$? After all $$t^2 e^tu(-t) =(-t)^2e^{-(-t)}u(-t)$$ which is just the first term reversed in time.You need to only calculate the first one,for this you can use a scaling of -1 for time and use the property.

Answer (score 0):

The key of your problem is how to define the absolute value.  I think you have to solve that integral, please look at the picture and let me know if it answers your question, regards:

[image]

Comment: i meant to say that the - sign exists BEFORE modulus